# kubernetes volume : One shared volume and one dedicate volume between replicated pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm new to Kubernetes and learning it. 
have deployment kind of pods and replcas=3.

Is there any way I can mount separate volume for each pod and one volume for all pods. 
Requirements:

case 1- My application that is generating some temp file name tempfile.txt, So there is three replica pod, each one will generate tempfile.txt but content might be different. So If I use shared volume that will override each other .
case-2: I have a common file that is not part of image, that will be used by all pods starting the application i.e copy files from host to all pods's container

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please elaborate your use case.

Comment: case 1- My application that is generating some temp file name tempfile.txt, So there is three replica pod, each one will generate tempfile.txt but content might be different. So If I use shared volume that will override each other .  case-2: I have a common file that is not part of image, that will be used by all pods starting the application.

Comment: Please update the question itself with complete requirements not in comment and share what have your tired up until now ?

Comment: You should explore using subPath in your mount option read more on this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

Comment: In case of subPath that will be shared between all pods. That works in case 2. But need seperate volume for pods that can be 3 , 4 or 10 pods replicas

Comment: You will need a statefull set and not a deployment then .. [refer this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the first part. Here is mine:

Instead of a deployment, use a statefulSet to create the replicas. statefulSets allow you to include a volume template which each pod have created with it, thus each new pod will have a new PV created specificlaly for it.

This does require your cluster to allow for [dynamically provisioned volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/).

Depending on the size of your tempfile.txt, your use case, and your cluster/node configuration, you might also want to consider using a [`hostPath` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) which will use the local storage of your node.

For the second part of your question, using any readWriteMany volume will work (such as any NFS option).

On the note of subPath, this should also work, so long as you define different subPaths for each pod. the example in the link provided by DT does this by creating a subpath based off the pod name.

Comment: if using hostPath if you want to share data then all pod will have to be on same node which will require affinity or nodeselector to be set.

Comment: I don't have pod level resource, I have deployment resource that configured as replicas=3 , that will create three pods with same configuration. Is it possible with Deployment?

Comment: If you want to stick with deployment, subPath is the best option. If the data does not need to persist, hostPath is fine. The key to hostPath is that you are treating it as a scratch space, it's not meant to persist or be shared